# Hensel's lemma for complete rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, hensels-lemma

Hensel's lemma can be stated as

> Let $A$ be a local ring complete by the maximal ideal $m$, and define $Q=A/m$. Let $f\in A[x]$ be a monic polynomial and define $\bar{f}\in Q[x]$ as the polynomial where the coefficients are reduced mod $m$. If we have monic polynomials $G,H\in Q[x]$ with $(G,H)=1$ such that $\bar{f}=GH$, then we have monic polynomials $g,h\in A[x]$ such that $f=gh$, $\bar{g}=G$ and $\bar{h}=H$.

I'm having trouble with completing the proof. So far I've proved by induction that for $i\geq 1$ we have $G_i, H_i\in A[x]$ such that $f=G_iH_i\ mod\ m^i[x]$ where  $\overline{G_i}=G$ and $\overline{H_i}=H$, with $\deg(G_i)=\deg(G)$ and $\deg(H_i)=\deg(H)$.

I then showed that coefficient wise $G_i$ and $H_i$ are Cauchy, and thus converge to coefficients $a_0,\ldots,a_{deg(G_i)-1}$ and $b_0,\ldots, b_{deg(H_i)-1}$ for  $G_i$ og $H_i$. Then if we let
\begin{align*}
g(x)=x^{deg(G_i)}+a_{deg(G_i)-1}x^{deg(G_i)-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0 \\
h(x)=x^{deg(H_i)}+b_{deg(H_i)-1}x^{deg(H_i)-1}+\ldots+b_1x+b_0 
\end{align*}
we have $\overline{g}=G$ og $\overline{h}=H$.

Now I need to show that $f=gh$, but I'm kinda stuck. It's not clear to me, why (or how) we have $f=gh$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use what you know about the various $G_j$, $H_j$ to show that $f = gh \mod m^i[x]$ for each $i$? (Hint: show that the $G_j$ etc are *unique*. That is, if $f = G_j H_j = G'_j H'_j \mod m^j[x]$, then $G_j = G'_j, H_j = H'_j$.)

Once you have this, then you know that $f - gh \in m^i[x]$ for each $i$, and hence $f - gh \in \bigcap_i m^i[x]$, i.e. the $x^k$-coefficient of $f - gh$ is in $\bigcap_i m^i$ for each $k$.

It remains to show that the $m$-adic filtration is *separated* on $A$ (which is a fancy way of saying $\bigcap_i m^i = 0$).

Recall that your local ring $(A,m)$ is *complete*, which Matsumura uses to mean that the natural map $\varphi: A\to \underset{\leftarrow n}{\lim} A/m^n$ is an isomorphism. (We'll only need it to be injective, actually.) Take any $x\in \bigcap_i m^i$: then the image of $x$ in each $A/m^n$ is $0$, and so $\varphi(x) = 0$, which implies that $x=0$ as $\varphi$ is injective.

Comment: What confuses me, is that it isn't mentioned anywhere in the book that local includes Noetherian. The book (Commutative Ring Theory by Matsumura) also waits to introduce Krull's intersection theorem before a  couple of pages after Hensel's lemma.

Comment: @Jta Sorry - I've spent way too long with my head in Bourbaki, which uses these terms slightly differently, and made the wrong terminological assumption. :) I've updated my answer! My confusion was that "complete" and "separated" are different things in Bourbaki-land, but nowadays I think most commutative algebraists have lumped them together into one single condition they call "complete".

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense now! How does the uniqueness of $G_j$ and $H_j$ imply $f=gh\mod m^i[x]$?

Comment: The idea is as follows. Suppose $f = G_i H_i \mod m^i[x]$, and $G_i$ and $H_i$ are *unique* such (subject to some properties). Then, when we find $G_{i+1}$ and $H_{i+1}$ satisfying $f = G_{i+1} H_{i+1} \mod m^{i+1}[x]$, we can reduce everything further mod $m^i[x]$, and we get $f = G_{i+1} H_{i+1} \mod m^i[x]$. Now the uniqueness tells us that we must have $G_{i+1} = G_i \mod m^i[x]$ and $H_{i+1} = H_i \mod m^i[x]$. More generally, $G_j = G_i \mod m^i[x]$ for all $j>i$, and so, by passing to the limit you've constructed, $g = G_i \mod m^i[x]$ for all $i$.